# How to Pause and resume a process in windows application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have created a windows application which is used to read every row from spreadsheet and pass each row of data to stored procedure. Assuming this work takes place for 2 hours(since there are large number of data's). And i have placed two buttons pause and cancel. On click of pasue, I need to pause the work of updating the work and need to resume when the button is pressed again. Please provide some inputs regarding this. I am using Visual studio 2003(with 1.1 framework) and SQL 2005. I am using c# for programming

```
Could you guys please explain how to put the main thread in background(while paused)... Please respond soon as it is urgent.
```

Comment: google for "producer consumer" and for "thread synchronisation" (semaphore).

Answer (score 1):

The operation of reading rows should be done on a separate thread. On that thread you should have something like this (note it is just the idea and not an exact code):

```
while(!mCancel)
{
   if(mPaused==true)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
   else
   {
       //do here the row reading
   }

}
```

The `mCancel` and `mPaused` are global flags that you set to true or false from the UI buttons. When you press Pause button you set mPaused to true. At this point the loop will sleep for 1 sec and then reiterate and check for the flag again and if needed will sleep again.

Another way would be to use the [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) class. See link for details. YHis class is used for signalign between threads, like the main thread and a worker thread for instance. [Here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/12/thread-and-sync-in-c/) is a sample.

**Edit:** The [definitive guide to multi-threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari. Read this and all your threading problems will be solved.

Comment: sleeping in a while loop is pretty lame but probably suffices for a lashed up in house code

Comment: @David: Yeah , I know. That is why I suggested the other way. But the Sleep method is easier to understand at first.

Comment: Could you guys please explain how to put the reading operation in seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

In order to track the state of your pause button, you need to let the application process incoming messages from time to time. The implementation depends on the programming language being used and possibly the application framework.